# Multiple Images coming from one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a webpage and want multiple images coming from one image using Javascript, CSS or Jquery whatever is required.

```
<img src="main.png" >
<img src="submain1.png" >
<img src="submain2.png" >
<img src="submain3.png" >
```

I am new to javascript and so it's getting difficult to solve it.
`main.png` is the main image and I want `submain1.png, submain2.png, submain3.png` images to come from the `main.png` one after the other as soon as the page loads.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by " want multiple images coming from one image".

Is it that you have some type of sprite sheet?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service... You must at least attempt to solve this issue yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is no "Do this for me"-site.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, we think you are asking about sprite sheets.  Now that you know a more common term for what you might be after you could try some searches.  There are lots of CSS sprite issues on this site:

[CSS Sprite Issues On StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css%20sprite)

This is a quick demo:

```css
#full { width: 389px; height: 186px; }
#window1 { background-position: 369px -11px; }
#window2 { background-position: 194px -91px; }

.iconback {
  border: solid 1px;
  background-image: url(http://www.icons-land.com/images/products/VistaPlayStopPauseIcons.jpg);
}

.window { width: 80px; height: 80px; margin: 1em; }
```

```html
<div id="full" class="iconback"></div>
<div id="window1" class="iconback window"></div>
<div id="window2" class="iconback window"></div>
```